# Error Value does not fall within the expected range on pdf creation using itextsharp

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a pdf of an invoice report and there is this exception throwing out that says "Value does not fall within the expected range".

Please see the code below:

```
foreach (var item in datagrid.ItemsSource.Cast<InvoiceDTO>())
{
reportTable.AddCell(item.Number);
reportTable.AddCell(item.Amount.ToString());
reportTable.AddCell(item.DisputeReason);
reportTable.AddCell(item.DateCreated);
reportTable.AddCell(item.CreatedBy);
reportTable.AddCell(item.PaymentOption);
reportTable.AddCell(item.PaymentDetails);
reportTable.AddCell(item.IsActive);
reportTable.AddCell(item.IsDisputed);
}
```

The exception is thrown specifying the paymentoption line in the above code.

I am a beginner and can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: What is does the exception say?

Comment: This is the exception "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Answer (score 0):

You get this error whenever the values you're adding to a cell is null, you can add a check or set a default value to any null items you're adding to a cell, something like this:

```
reportTable.AddCell(item.Number ?? string.Empty);
```